# Workflow e-mail to external address

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-designer

I want to use a Workflow to send an e-mail to an external address but SharePoint Designer 2013 won't let me do this.  Searching the web tells me to use a SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflow but I get an error message saying "Microsoft SharePoint Designer cannot be used to edit web sites on servers different from Microsoft Server 2010." Could someone please lay out in simple steps how I can send my external e-mail?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to send an email to an external address in a Workflow on SharePoint Online. 
You need to use SharePoint Designer 2013 and in it you need to create the SharePoint 2010 Workflow (you can choose that option on the initial screen for creating the workflow). Then, you can add "Send email" action to the workflow, where you can add external address in to/cc/bcc fields.

You were on right track, but instead of creating the SharePoint 2010 Workflow in the SharePoint Designer 2013, you installed SharePoint Designer 2010 (I guess that from the error that you pasted here).

One more thing: If you have requirement that your main workflow must be SharePoint 2013 workflow, you can still create a 2010 workflow with only one action (send email), create the initiation parameter for it (the email address), and then use the "Start SharePoint 2010 workflow" action to start the workflow and pass it the requested email address as the parameter.

Comment: Damjan,  Many thanks for you help - problem solved.